# How to run next.js project

Tags: next.js, postcss

I am new to next.js. I have just created my first next.js project. But I could not run my project.

`npm run dev` throws below error.

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: Did you try adding post-css or sass related dependencies? Try removing them and first get the next app running then add them one by one

Comment: @juliomalves

```{
  "name": "next-crash-course",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}```

Comment: can we run .next ( generated using next build command ) folder individually?